# Sitecore 8.2 update 5 Ninject Solr support package issue

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, ninject

I am facing an issue with Ninject IOC container.

I am using Sitecore 8.2 update 5 and switching from Lucene to Solr search engine using the steps mentioned in https://sitecorerockz.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/lucene-to-solr/

I am using Solr 6.6.3. Earlier this project was on Sitecore 6.X version and from time to time some upgrades happened, and now it is in Sitecore 8.2 update 5.
The same Solr setup is working fine for the fresh Sitecore 8.2 update 5 setup.

I created Solr diagnostic page and kept it in `/Sitecore/admin` folder to check the error details, I am getting the below error for all the indexes:

> Solr Indexes Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ISolrOperations`1, key "sitecore_analytics_index" ---> Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}} No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path: 1) Request for ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}} Suggestions: 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}}. 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel. 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel. 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name. 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct. at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 376 at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, String name, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 164 at MyLibrary.test.Infrastructure.NinjectServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in C:\test_Git\Sitecore\src\test\Infrastructure\NinjectServiceLocator.cs:line 15 at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 49 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 53 at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 103 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Initialize() at ASP._Page_sitecore_admin_solr_diagnostic_cshtml.Execute() in c:\test_Git\Sitecore\build\25Sep2019\Website\sitecore\admin\solr-diagnostic.cshtml:line 29

What am I missing, could you please advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SetLocatorProvider was getting initialized two times

- Modified the Custom code related to Ninject IOC
- Our current solution was using Ninject.dll 3.0.0.0 now I used new version of Ninject.dll which is  3.2.2.0  under folder  bin>>Social
- Replaced all the Solr dll files from fresh Sitecore 8.2 update 5 files